# How can I use the jQuery Round Corner plugin to make round corners?

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, jquery-plugins

I need a round corner on my website. I'm fairly inexperienced with jQuery and JavaScript in general; what's the proper way to load and call this plugin?

Comment: You need more details to your question, seems like you just want us to do all the work for you.

Comment: if your users are pretty tech-savvy, you can do this with just CSS.  Safari and FF both support rounded corners in CSS.  if you have to support IE users, though, you need the plugin

Comment: @Jakub The details are there. How do you achieve rounded corners using jQuery, and CSS.

Comment: @Kip. There are tech savvy users who use IE.

Comment: @Rajasekar: How about choosing an "accepted answer" if it worked?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use the jquery.corner.js and in your script, just add

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#box1").corner();
});
```

And in your mark-up, you're supposed to have:

```
<div id="box1"></div>
```

You can check out the jQuery [Rounded Corners Tutorial](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Rounded_Corners) for more.

Comment: where i have to include this @Randell

Comment: <script> $(this).corner(); </script> Like this?    @randell

Comment: Yes, I also edited the sample for your convenience.  Make sure you've added the jquery.js and jquery.corner.js.

Comment: Is there some associated css to go with this? It does not seem to work for me.

Answer (score 5):

**1. Add this code to your head section (assuming your jquery is local):**

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.3.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.corner.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
      $(function(){
          $('div.round').each(function() {
              var q = $(this).corner("rounded 7px");
              eval(q);
          });
      });
</script>
```

**2. Add the class="round" to a div wrapper**

```
<div class="round"></div>
```

- Just add the class="round" to any div
  you want on your page.
- Change the 7px value to adjust the
  "roundness" of the corner.  A higher
  number is more round.

Answer (score 3):

I would say [go with css3](http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/). For Firefox it's:

```
.roundedCorners { -moz-border-radius: 5px; }
```

For Safari/Chorme it's:

```
.roundedCorners { -webkit-border-radius: 5px; }
```

And I'd stop there. Since this is purely a presentation/appearance thing I wouldn't mess with the JavaScript solutions. If your users aren't using a browser that supports css3, they just won't get rounded corners.

Comment: No, IE doesn't support CSS3 :(